# Convert to nested pojo class using inner class

Tags: jackson, pojo

My Json:

```
[
    {
        "accountId": "1005003805",
        "status": "1000",
        "internalStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "associations": [
            {
                "id": "1000004114",
                "type": "reseller"
            }
        ],
        "preferredLanguage": "it-IT",
        "address": {
            "country": "IT",
            "phoneNumber": "408-536-3538",
            "city": "SESTO FIORENTINO",
            "postalCode": "50019",
            "addressLine1": "345 Park Ave",
            "addressLine2": "VIA DONINZETTI 17",
            "region": "32"
        },
        "name": "UPLOAD DI RICCI LUCA E PROCELLI SNC anil",
        "type": "customer",
        "externalReferenceId": "Su66353456234",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "firstName": "su",
                "lastName": "ku",
                "phoneNumber": "408-536-3538",
                "type": "ADMIN",
                "email": "dis+testingapi@adobetest.com",
                "adminId": "6436457474D"
            }
        ],
        "createdDate": "2019-11-08T13:54:30.000+0000",
        "statusReason": "Account is activated",
        "accountCode": "21",
        "tenantId": "5tetewt3532",
        "cotermDate": ""
    },
    {
        "accountId": "1000004114",
        "status": "1000",
        "internalStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "associations": [
            {
                "id": "1655325",
                "type": "distributor"
            }
        ],
        "preferredLanguage": "it-IT",
        "address": {
            "country": "IT",
            "phoneNumber": "",
            "city": "San Giuliano",
            "postalCode": "20098",
            "addressLine1": "Via L. Tolstoi 65",
            "addressLine2": "",
            "region": "47"
        },
        "name": "Ad6745e53262362",
        "type": "reseller",
        "externalReferenceId": "re634le75358932",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "firstName": "Abc",
                "lastName": "An",
                "phoneNumber": "408-536-3538",
                "type": "ADMIN",
                "email": "a@adobe.com",
                "adminId": ""
            }
        ],
        "createdDate": "2019-11-08T06:35:58.000+0000",
        "statusReason": "Account is activated",
        "accountCode": "11",
        "tenantId": "",
        "cotermDate": ""
    },
    {
        "accountId": "16364649",
        "status": "1000",
        "internalStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "associations": [],
        "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
        "address": {
            "country": "IT",
            "phoneNumber": "",
            "city": "San Giuliano",
            "postalCode": "20098",
            "addressLine1": "Via L. Tolstoi 65",
            "addressLine2": "",
            "region": "47"
        },
        "name": "Stage Tech Data Italy",
        "type": "distributor",
        "externalReferenceId": "invalid",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "firstName": "arr",
                "lastName": "dummy",
                "phoneNumber": "",
                "type": "ADMIN",
                "email": "aty+vmp8@adobetest.com",
                "adminId": ""
            }
        ],
        "statusReason": "Manually created for testing",
        "accountCode": "01",
        "tenantId": "6456",
        "cotermDate": ""
    }
]
```

```
package adobe_Partner_Api_ECCS_PojoClasses;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class ECCSGetExtraCustomer {

    private String accountId;
    private String status;
    private String internalStatus;
    private String statusReason;
    private String externalReferenceId;
    private String tenantId;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String marketSegment;
    private String preferredLanguage;
    private String cotermDate;
    private String creationDate;
    private Address address;
    private ArrayList<Contacts> contacts;
    private ArrayList<Associations> associations;

    public ArrayList<Contacts> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(ArrayList<Contacts> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public ArrayList<Associations> getAssociations() {
        return associations;
    }

    public void setAssociations(ArrayList<Associations> associations) {
        this.associations = associations;
    }

    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getInternalStatus() {
        return internalStatus;
    }

    public void setInternalStatus(String internalStatus) {
        this.internalStatus = internalStatus;
    }

    public String getStatusReason() {
        return statusReason;
    }

    public void setStatusReason(String statusReason) {
        this.statusReason = statusReason;
    }

    public String getExternalReferenceId() {
        return externalReferenceId;
    }

    public void setExternalReferenceId(String externalReferenceId) {
        this.externalReferenceId = externalReferenceId;
    }

    public String getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMarketSegment() {
        return marketSegment;
    }

    public void setMarketSegment(String marketSegment) {
        this.marketSegment = marketSegment;
    }

    public String getPreferredLanguage() {
        return preferredLanguage;
    }

    public void setPreferredLanguage(String preferredLanguage) {
        this.preferredLanguage = preferredLanguage;
    }

    public String getCotermDate() {
        return cotermDate;
    }

    public void setCotermDate(String cotermDate) {
        this.cotermDate = cotermDate;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public static class Address {
        private String country;
        private String region;
        private String city;
        private String addressLine1;
        private String addressLine2;
        private String postalCode;
        private String phoneNumber;

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getRegion() {
            return region;
        }

        public void setRegion(String region) {
            this.region = region;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getAddressLine1() {
            return addressLine1;
        }

        public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
            this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
        }

        public String getAddressLine2() {
            return addressLine2;
        }

        public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
            this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
        }

        public String getPostalCode() {
            return postalCode;
        }

        public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
            this.postalCode = postalCode;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

    }

    public static class Contacts {
        private String type;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String adminId;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

        public String getAdminId() {
            return adminId;
        }

        public void setAdminId(String adminId) {
            this.adminId = adminId;
        }

    }

    public static class Associations {
        private String type;
        private String id;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
}
```

```
Error Message:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"[{"accountId":"1005003805","status":"1000","internalStatus":"ACTIVE","associations":[{"id":"1000004114","type":"reseller"}],"preferredLanguage":"it-IT","address":{"country":"IT","phoneNumber":"408-536-3538","city":"SESTO FIORENTINO","postalCode":"50019","addressLine1":"345 Park Ave","addressLine2":"VIA DONINZETTI 17","region":"32"},"name":"UPLOAD DI RICCI LUCA E PROCELLI SNC anil","type":"customer","externalReferenceId":"Su66353456234","contacts":[{"firstName":"surendra1","lastName":"kumar","pho"[truncated 1565 chars]; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: adobe_Partner_Api_ECCS_PojoClasses.ECCSGetExtraCustomer["accountId"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you put the *@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)* annotation on top of your class, which I think is unnecessary in your case.

There are also some errors in your POJO class, it misses the accountCode field, and the createdDate field is named creationDate.

```java
public class ECCSGetExtraCustomer {

    private String accountId;
    private String accountCode;
    private String createdDate;
    //... + Getters and setters
}
```

To deserialize your json as list you can do it this way :

```java
public class LaunchDebug {

    public void main() throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<ECCSGetExtraCustomer> eccsGetExtraCustomer = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(value, ECCSGetExtraCustomer[].class));
        System.out.println(eccsGetExtraCustomer.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: I need to serialize as this is a response json. I am not sure how to do it. Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question with a clear description of what you're trying to do and how you try to do it. It's hard to understand what you want to do with just code. I assumed you failed to deserialize your JSON into an object based on your error message, but then you state that the problem is about serialization.